# ColdFusion Using Custom Tags Within Custom Tags

Tags: coldfusion, custom-tags

I'm a bit new to ColdFusion (coming from Java/OOP world)

I have a custom tag that runs some things inside a cfscript and outputs a value. I'd like to have this custom tag (let's call it A) call another custom tag (let's call it B, a more general custom tag that has a sort of 'static' function) with a certain parameter.

How do I call B from within A?
How do I use the return value from B in A?

A's code

```
<cfscript>
     //Call to other custom tag here?:
     //foo = [CUSTOMTAG param="stuff"];
     value = foo;
</cfscript>
<cfoutput>#value#</cfoutput>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I ended up doing. In my "A" file (recall, A calls B):

```
<cfscript>
b = createObject("component","bName");
returnVal = b.method("paramInfo");
</cfscript>
```

In my "B" file

```
<cfcomponent displayname="bName">
<cffunction name="method" returntype="string" output="false">
<cfargument name="paramName" required="yes" type="string">
<cfscript>
 returnVal = paramName;
</cfscript>
<cfreturn returnVal>
</cffunction>
</cfcomponent>
```

Answer (score 6):

Are you maintaining some old code? Otherwise, writing a User-defined function would be way easier for you to use and/or to test than using an old-school custom tag.

While custom tag is good at doing things like generating markups, it's not that good at returning variable.

You should be looking into writing user-defined function (UDF) instead, just like how you'd do in Java.

Not saying custom tag can't return value(s), it is just not as natural as function.

To return values from a custom tag, you need to make use of `Caller` scope (which maps to the `variables` scope of the caller).  Something like...

```
<!--- customTag.cfm --->
<cfset caller[attributes.returnVar] = "some value">
```

And call the customTag like this:

```
<cf_customTag returnVar="foo">

<cfdump var="#variables.foo#">
```

Just keep track of who's the caller, and set the value in the caller scope, and you can invoke custom tag inside a custom tag, inside a custom tag, inside a custom tag...

If you need to capture the output of a custom tag into a var, wrap the custom tag call inside a `<cfsavecontent>` `</cfsavecontent>`.

Comment: Great comment Henry.  I wonder if JMoy is trying to figure out how to call his other custom tag from *within cfscript* though? Not sure I have an answer to that. I think actually I would create a function using cffunction that calls his second custom tag - then call that function within the cfscript... sort of a wrapper.